# Google ruby api client error with youtube upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to set up a service that helps manage a user's youtube account, including scheduled video uploads even when the user is not logged in. I'm having some weird issues with authentication, and I can't seem to find a way to fix it.

My omniauth initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    {
      name: 'google',
      scope: 'http://gdata.youtube.com, email, profile, plus.me, youtube, youtube.upload',
      prompt: 'consent',
      access_type: 'offline',
      image_aspect_ratio: 'square
    }
end
```

The brunt of my code for authorization:

```
YOUTUBE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'

account = User.find(1234)
client = Google::APIClient.new(application_name: 'YouTube Delivery',
                               application_version: '1.0.0')
api = client.discovered_api('youtube', 'v3')

client.authorization.client_id = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID']
client.authorization.client_secret = ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
client.authorization.grant_type = 'refresh_token'
client.authorization.refresh_token = account.refresh_token
client.authorization.scope = YOUTUBE_SCOPE
client.authorization.fetch_access_token! if client.authorization.expired?
```

All of this code appears to work. A user can sign in, and I've verified that the proper permissions are being asked for. A user is also prompted to give offline consent. I get back a refresh token, and I am able to get new access tokens with the refresh token when the current token is expired. No problems there.

The problems come in when I try to upload a video to youtube when the user is not present:

```
video = Video.find(1234)
request_body = {
  snippet: {
    title: video.title,
    description: video.youtube_description,
    tags: video.tags
  },
  status: { privacyStatus: 'private' }
}

response = client.execute!(
  api_method: api.videos.insert,
  body_object: request_body,
  media: Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(video.local_path, 'video/*'),
  parameters: {
    uploadType: 'resumable',
    part: 'snippet,status'
  },
  authorization: client.authorization
)
```

This is where google throws back `Google::APIClient::AuthorizationError: Unauthorized`

Per the [google docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#OAuth2_Calling_a_Google_API), I can test the access token I have by running:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

For me, this returns:

```
 { "error": {
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain": "usageLimits",
       "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
       "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
       "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
     }
   ],
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }}
```

I've made sure I've added the following apis to my project in the google api console: contacts, google+, youtube data, youtube analytics. I've also checked that all of my environment variables are properly set.

Not really sure where to go from here. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

My rails version: 4.1.6